# How many different strings of 5 lower case letters are there?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many different strings of 5 lower case letters are there? Assume that letters may repeat and the string must contain at least one letter a?
I tried  this:
5×26^5=5×26 ×26 ×26 ×26=2684880

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(26)^5 - (25)^5.$

First term is total # of 5 character strings, where each character has 26 choices.

Second term is total # of 5 character strings, where each character has only 25 choices, re no "a" is used.

The difference between the two is the # of 5 character strings with at least 1 "a".

Answer (score 0):

Break it into five sub-problems:  exactly 1 $A$, exactly 2 $A$s, ..., exactly 5 $A$s.

One $A$:  There are five places for the required $A$, and $25^4$ ways to fill the remaining four slots without the use of another $A$.

Two $A$s:  There are ${5 \choose 2}$ ways to place the two $A$s, and $25^3$ ways to fill the remaining $s$ slots with letters other than $A$.

...

Five $A$s:  There is ${5 \choose 5} = 1$ way to fill with all five $A$s.

Add these up.